# Change default value on core node/add forms after submit

Tags: nodes

I'm using the core **node/add/** url to create content in my site. I have a date field that defaults to now. I'm also using the **add another module**.

Is it possible to change the default value to the last one submitted when the user chooses the option to submit and add another?

So, if a user creates a content with **date=2019/01/12**, when he clicks submit and add another, the form should show with the same date value.

Comment: You’d have to achieve this with custom code and hook_form_alter most likely.

Comment: sounds like a bug to me...

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bug but the concept of the module should set the default values of the form to the previously submitted ones. I think I will have to do it with the hook_form_alter...